# Starting a forge minecraft server with the dawncraft modpack issues on Linux CentOS stream 9:

Tags: java, server, terminal, centos, minecraft-forge

I do infact have jdk-20 installed. Below is the result of executing ./run.sh

[13:06:00] [main/WARN] [ne.mi.fm.lo.mo.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file /home/lgallo/Minecraft_Server/Server/libraries/net/minecraftforge/fmlcore/1.18.2-40.2.1/fmlcore-1.18.2-40.2.1.jar is missing mods.toml file
[13:06:00] [main/WARN] [ne.mi.fm.lo.mo.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file /home/lgallo/Minecraft_Server/Server/libraries/net/minecraftforge/javafmllanguage/1.18.2-40.2.1/javafmllanguage-1.18.2-40.2.1.jar is missing mods.toml file
[13:06:00] [main/WARN] [ne.mi.fm.lo.mo.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file /home/lgallo/Minecraft_Server/Server/libraries/net/minecraftforge/lowcodelanguage/1.18.2-40.2.1/lowcodelanguage-1.18.2-40.2.1.jar is missing mods.toml file
[13:06:00] [main/WARN] [ne.mi.fm.lo.mo.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file /home/lgallo/Minecraft_Server/Server/libraries/net/minecraftforge/mclanguage/1.18.2-40.2.1/mclanguage-1.18.2-40.2.1.jar is missing mods.toml file
[13:06:00] [main/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.lo.mo.JarInJarDependencyLocator/]: Found 1 dependencies adding them to mods collection
[13:06:00] [main/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.lo.ModSorter/LOADING]: Missing or unsupported mandatory dependencies:
Mod ID: 'forge', Requested by: 'chunky', Expected range: '[41,)', Actual version: '40.2.1'
Mod ID: 'minecraft', Requested by: 'chunky', Expected range: '[1.19.3,1.20)', Actual version: '1.18.2'
[13:06:04] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: Compatibility level set to JAVA_17
[13:06:04] [main/ERROR] [mixin/]: Mixin config pmmo.mixins.json does not specify "minVersion" property
[13:06:04] [main/ERROR] [mixin/]: Mixin config rei-jei-internals-workaround.mixins.json does not specify "minVersion" property
[13:06:04] [main/ERROR] [mixin/]: Mixin config itshallnottick.mixins.json does not specify "minVersion" property
[13:06:04] [main/ERROR] [mixin/]: Mixin config polylib.mixins.json does not specify "minVersion" property
[13:06:05] [main/ERROR] [mixin/]: Mixin config rei.mixins.json does not specify "minVersion" property
[13:06:05] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: Successfully loaded Mixin Connector [com.sonicether.soundphysics.MixinConnector]
[13:06:05] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: Successfully loaded Mixin Connector [tictim.paraglider.MixinConnector]
[13:06:05] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: Successfully loaded Mixin Connector [ca.spottedleaf.starlight.mixin.MixinConnector]
[13:06:05] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Launching target 'forgeserver' with arguments []
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'wildbackport-forge-refmap.json' for wildbackport.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'yungsbridges.refmap.json' for yungsbridges.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'yungsbridges.refmap.json' for yungsbridges_forge.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'yungsextras.refmap.json' for yungsextras.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'yungsextras.refmap.json' for yungsextras_forge.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'untamedwilds.refmap.json' for untamedwilds.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'thirst.refmap.json' for villagercomfort.mixin.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'idas.refmap.json' for idas.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'antiqueatlas-forge-refmap.json' for antiqueatlas.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'insanelib.refmap.json' for insanelib.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'piglinproliferation.refmap.json' for piglinproliferation.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'polylib-common-refmap.json' for polylib.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'creativecore.mixins.refmap.json' for creativecore.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:05] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'nethersdelight.refmap.json' for nethersdelight.mixins.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: net/minecraft/client/model/IronGolemModel (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.client.model.IronGolemModel)
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: @Mixin target net.minecraft.client.model.IronGolemModel was not found strawgolem.mixins.json:IronGolemModelMixin
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: net/minecraft/client/model/geom/ModelPart (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.client.model.geom.ModelPart)
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: @Mixin target net.minecraft.client.model.geom.ModelPart was not found wildbackport-common.mixins.json:access.ModelPartAccessor
[13:06:06] [main/FATAL] [ne.mi.fm.lo.RuntimeDistCleaner/DISTXFORM]: Attempted to load class net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderType for invalid dist DEDICATED_SERVER
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderType (java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to load class net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderType for invalid dist DEDICATED_SERVER)
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: @Mixin target net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderType was not found wildbackport-common.mixins.json:access.RenderTypeAccessor
[13:06:06] [main/FATAL] [ne.mi.fm.lo.RuntimeDistCleaner/DISTXFORM]: Attempted to load class net/minecraft/client/renderer/Sheets for invalid dist DEDICATED_SERVER
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: net/minecraft/client/renderer/Sheets (java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to load class net/minecraft/client/renderer/Sheets for invalid dist DEDICATED_SERVER)
[13:06:06] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: @Mixin target net.minecraft.client.renderer.Sheets was not found wildbackport-common.mixins.json:access.SheetsAccessor
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[13:06:07] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/List (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
Exception in thread "main" org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.throwables.MixinTransformerError: An unexpected critical error was encountered
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinProcessor.applyMixins(MixinProcessor.java:392)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClass(MixinTransformer.java:250)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.service.modlauncher.MixinTransformationHandler.processClass(MixinTransformationHandler.java:131)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinLaunchPluginLegacy.processClass(MixinLaunchPluginLegacy.java:131)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.serviceapi.ILaunchPluginService.processClassWithFlags(ILaunchPluginService.java:156)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchPluginHandler.offerClassNodeToPlugins(LaunchPluginHandler.java:88)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.ClassTransformer.transform(ClassTransformer.java:120)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader.maybeTransformClassBytes(TransformingClassLoader.java:50)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@1.0.3/cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader.readerToClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:110)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@1.0.3/cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader.lambda$findClass$16(ModuleClassLoader.java:216)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@1.0.3/cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader.loadFromModule(ModuleClassLoader.java:226)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@1.0.3/cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:216)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:633)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:585)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:560)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/fmlloader@1.18.2-40.2.1/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonServerLaunchHandler.lambda$launchService$0(CommonServerLaunchHandler.java:32)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:53)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:71)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:106)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:77)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23)
at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher@1.0.0/cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:149)
Caused by: org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.throwables.ClassMetadataNotFoundException: java.util.List
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.transformMethod(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:754)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.transform(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:739)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.attach(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:310)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.createContextFor(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:280)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinInfo.createContextFor(MixinInfo.java:1288)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinApplicatorStandard.apply(MixinApplicatorStandard.java:292)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.TargetClassContext.apply(TargetClassContext.java:383)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.TargetClassContext.applyMixins(TargetClassContext.java:365)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.spongepowered.mixin/org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinProcessor.applyMixins(MixinProcessor.java:363)
... 23 more

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling jdk, I completely reinstalled my OS to start from scratch with a gui to get the correct files for sure and I ended up with the same results as last time.